# How to limit the amount of characters displayed on the table

Tags: reactjs

How to limit the amount of characters displayed on the table? All of the data is being displayed and is making the table look very long. I want to limit the amount of characters displayed. The data is coming from Firebase realtime database.

The code is below:

```
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
      <table className="styled-table">
        
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>No.</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Table Entry</th>
          

            {!sort && <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Action</th>}
         

          </tr>
        </thead>
        {!sort && (
          <tbody>
            {Object.keys(data).map((id, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={id}>
                  <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                  <td>{data[id].tableentry}</td>
                  <td>
           

                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        )}
       
      </table>
     

    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Data in firebase is ordered lexicographically, so you'll have to get the last of them.

```
return firebase.database().ref('someRef').orderByChild("orderByTerm").limitToLast(3);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Query#limittolast